# How to derive max date on LISTAGG Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, date, max, listagg

Oracle 12c installation. I am having trouble organizing Oracle `listagg()` to show the count of cars column of my query to display the results of only the max(inventory_date) data per location.

I was thinking to create a view to aggregate the results:

```
create or replace view car_inventory_vw as 
select max(a.inventory_date) as max_date,
a.location,LISTAGG(a.COUNT_CARS||' '||a.EQUIPMENT_TYPE,',')
within GROUP (ORDER BY a.equipment_type) as equipment_list 
from car_equipment a 
group by a.location;
```

Create the table and insert test rows, Installed on Oracle 12c on Windows

```
CREATE TABLE "CAR_EQUIPMENT" 
   (    "COUNT_CARS" NUMBER(10,0), 
"EQUIPMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"LOCATION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"INVENTORY_DATE" DATE) 
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION,     INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-09-07 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('9', 'Jaguars', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-09-07 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('7', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-08-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('10','Trans Am', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-08-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-01-07 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (COUNT_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('4', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-01-08 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Results should be the inventory list of the max(inventory_date) by location:

```
MAX(INVENTORY_DATE) LOCATION    INVENTORY_LIST
-------------------- ----------- -------------------------
2019-08-30          leamington  10 Trans AM, 7 Rovers
2019-09-07          coventry    8 Rovers, 9 Jaguars
```

I am stuck on a simple problem, please advise how I can get the list created for the max date data only by location.

Thank you in advance,
Gilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could proceed in two steps :

- first, use `RANK()` in a subquery to identify the records that correspond to the latest inventory date at each location
- then, use aggregation in the outer query and generate the inventory list of each location using `LISTAGG()`

Query:

```
SELECT 
    inventory_date max_inventory_date,
    location,
    LISTAGG(count_cars || ' ' || equipment_type, ', ') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY equipment_type) inventory_list
FROM (
    SELECT c.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY location ORDER BY inventory_date DESC) rn
    FROM car_equipment c
) x 
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY inventory_date, location;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e6ad4b368d71cd23742b45fde08e24b)**

Data:

```
COUNT_CARS | EQUIPMENT_TYPE | LOCATION   | INVENTORY_DATE
---------: | :------------- | :--------- | :-------------
         8 | Rovers         | coventry   | 07-SEP-19     
         9 | Jaguars        | coventry   | 07-SEP-19     
         7 | Rovers         | leamington | 30-AUG-19     
        10 | Trans Am       | leamington | 30-AUG-19     
         8 | Rovers         | coventry   | 07-JAN-19     
         4 | Rovers         | leamington | 08-JAN-19
```

Results:

```
MAX_INVENTORY_DATE | LOCATION   | INVENTORY_LIST       
:----------------- | :--------- | :--------------------
30-AUG-19          | leamington | 7 Rovers, 10 Trans Am
07-SEP-19          | coventry   | 9 Jaguars, 8 Rovers
```

Comment: How would you show the cobined data from a date instead of the max date?